# Spawned multiprocessing processes aren't doing any work

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a csv file with 1000s of rows that I'm using to make an api call to create a user. The script does spawn new processes, but those process sit idle while the main thread does all the work.

Here is what I've tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import set_start_method
import multiprocessing
import requests
import csv
from csv import writer

set_start_method("spawn", force=True)

def create_user(multi_csv):
    for row in multi_csv:
        csv_email = row[0]
        csv_first_name = row[1]
        csv_last_name = row[3]
        create_data = "{\"email\":\"" + csv_email + "\",\"firstName\":\"" + csv_first_name + "\",\"lastName\":\"" + csv_last_name + "\"}}"
        r = requests.post("https://url.com", data=create_data, headers={"Authorization":"authinfo"})

        print(str(csv_email))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("csv.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
        multi_csv = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

    with Pool(4) as pool:
        pool.apply_async(create_user(multi_csv))
```

Comment: You are not passing a callback, but rather the executed function. Don't call create_user

Comment: Right now, you're attempting to move all the work from the main process, to one single worker process. So all you're doing is adding inter-process communication overhead to send your list to the worker, and then the final string back, without actually parallelizing anything. If your bottleneck here is the `requests.post` call, you should farm each those off to a pool of worker threads (not processes, since the requests call is likely I/O bound), rather than processing the entire CSV file in a single worker process, and sending each request sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you call create_user with list once and I believe that is the issue. I would try to run it as in documentation example in [Documentation - Introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction)

From

```
with Pool(4) as pool:
    pool.apply_async(create_user(multi_csv))
```

i would try to call it this way:

```
with Pool(4) as pool:
    pool.map(create_user, multi_csv)
```

or use apply_async, but don't use list as parameter for function:

```
with Pool(4) as pool:
    pool.apply_async(create_user, multi_csv)
```

Comment: ```
with Pool(4) as pool:
    pool.map(create_user, multi_csv)
```
This did it for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have problem with the apply_async call.

Try changing the last line to:

```
pool.apply_async(create_user, (multi_csv,))
```

The tuple for the argc is very imported → [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

You are not passing the function to `apply_async` you are only passing the return value. So you have to provide a valid callback, which `apply_async` can call on demand.

If it doesn't solve the problem, please supply some test data.